# Icecast multiple source same mountpoint/stream

Tags: icecast

I've been trying to find an answer to this question and not sure i possible.

The scenario:

My friend and I want to host a live stock trading alert broadcast. I have Icecast setup successfully on a linux server and am able to broadcast my voice using the BUTT encoder/client. This all works fine. But  is there anyway to get my friend in a different location broadcasting on the same mountpoint/stream? I've tried starting BUTT as a second client on the same mountpoint, and it simply won't connect. I we set up a different mounpoint/stream, the end user (with a web player) can only listen to one stream at a time by default.

So is there anyway to mix the streams? Share the stream with two sources?

My only thought at this point is to have two web players on the web page, have them hidden and auto start them at the same time when the user gets to the page.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible, Icecast is not intended for this usecase, so you might want to use something like [Mumble](http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Main_Page) to talk together and stream the Mumble audio to Icecast, instead of having both of you streaming to Icecast.